# Adding a theme option to the admin that lets me turn on/off a javascript file

Tags: plugins, theme-options, options

I want to add a theme option to the Wordpress admin so that I don't need to commit code every time I need to "activate" (or deactivate by commenting out) an Optimizely javascript snippet I only want run occasionally.

I googled this question, but most of the posts I saw were related to to running CSS or JS on the admin page, and weren't related to adding a theme option.

I'm not sure how to get started. Do I have to register a setting (http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API#Adding_Setting_Fields)?

If so, in which file do I add add_settings_field function? Functions.php?

Answer (score 1):

Yep you can use `add_settings()` to create the setting itself. There is an example in the codex.

This example code could go in your themes `functions.php` file or in a plugin file, it's up to you.

Then in the header template all you would have to do is use an `if` statement to check what the value of the aforementioned setting was and either output the `JS` link or not based upon this variable.